# Использование css и bootstrap

Tags: css, вёрстка

Занимаюсь вёрсткой около года. В данный момент пишу проект для моего диплома. Использую bootstrap и часто приходится добавлять свои правки css, например, что сдвинуть, убрать padding или margin у элементов. В общем постоянные css костыли.
Не является ли это плохим тоном ? Хочется писать чистый, качественный код, но все время кажется, что мой код ужасен.

Comment: доработку существующего решения под себя, я  затрудняюсь назвать *дурным тоном*, но если доработок становится слишком много, то в этом случае надо поискать или другой инструмент или сделать все самому

Comment: Надеюсь в этом нет ничего противозаконного. Просто кажется, что если использую css фреймворк, вносить какие то правки это не есть хорошо

Comment: Любая библиотека - это зло....  Чистый качественный код, это когда с первой строчки `css` пишешь сам.....  Да и не только `css`

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно использовать именно css файл. Можно использовать исходники бутстрапа на SCSS, задать где надо нужные отступы, цвета и тд, и скомпилировать, и не будет никакого переписывания правил.

Comment: Это само собой, дело в другом. К примеру, часто приходится убирать отступы у col-* или если margin и padding компенсируют друг друга

Comment: Значит ты что-то не так делаешь. Раз тебе приходится убирать постоянно отступы у колонок. Добавление враппера решит проблему.